# Как получить текст из файла с расширением .py?

Tags: python

Есть скрипт, который сохранен с расширением .py. Хотелось бы получить текст скрипта и работать с ним. Изменил расширение файла на .txt и прочитал как обычный текстовый файл, но это требует ручного вмешательства. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы на входе был файл.py и текст файла автоматически из него доставался, и с ним можно работать как со строкой?

Answer (score 1):

Файл `.py` ничем не отличается от файла `.txt`, поскольку информация в нем хранится в незашифрованном виде и вы можете прочитать его стандартными методами языка `Python`:

```
with open('test_file.py', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(data)
```

Comment: А действительно работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

правой кнопкой - открыть с помошью - другая программа - выбрать блокнот...

Comment: Да так можно, но нужно чтобы программа именно из файла .py доставал текст. То есть дали программе файл.py  и она записала его содержимое в переменную

Comment: на чем написать программу?

Comment: на python естественно)